# Python parallelization of tasks (event loop?)

Tags: python, parallel-processing, subprocess, twisted, gevent

#### Current Situation

I'm writing [a small Python program](https://github.com/dbrgn/orochi) to play playlists from 8tracks in your terminal.

It consists of three parts, a `client.py` using the stdlib's [cmd](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cmd.html) module, an `api.py` module that uses python-requests to access the API and a `player.py` module that creates an mplayer subprocess in slave mode and sends commands to it.

#### Problem

This works so far, the problem is that I have no other way to tell if a song has finished playing in mplayer except for polling the subprocess' stdout. This means I have to watch the process so I can request and start the next song of the playlist after a song has finished playing.

The problem is that waiting for the subprocess would block the `cmd` module's main loop. I can't simply run it in a separate thread or process either though, because I would have to share the reference to the subprocess' stdout, and references like these can't be shared between processes.

#### Possible approaches

I thought of different solutions for this. I could put `player.py` in a separate process and send text-commands via a queue, but that would overcomplicate things. I could create a Twisted app, but Twisted is pretty big and I don't know where to start. Also, I'd prefer not to have such a dependency in my project.

A third solution would be to use Gevent. The question is how I would get this to work with the `cmd` module. As far as I understood Gevent, I would have to yield in every place where I'm "waiting" for something. In this case, this would be during the HTTP requests, when waiting during the `cmd.cmdloop()` and in the pauses between the subprocess polling. But how do I get the `cmd` module to yield? Some kind of subclass or monkey patching?

Comment: Why would you prefer "not to have such a dependency in your project"?  What is "such a dependency" anyway?  How is depending on Gevent or Python interestingly different from depending on Twisted?

Comment: It's just that I perceived Twisted as a "huge project" and that I don't know it well, that's all. But I'm not completely against it, as long as it works in my situation without rewriting all my code :)

Comment: Why can't you just have a command output tailer thread?  Sharing fds between processes is tricky, but between threads this should be doable.

Comment: @fmoo Hm, so far I only tried `multiprocessing.dummy` (which uses threads), which can't do such things. But maybe I should try to use `Threading` directly instead...

Comment: Can you post some of your (simplified?) code for `player.py`?  I've totally split subprocess tailers out into their own threads in the past without problems.  `multiprocessing.dummy` should be able to work as well.

Comment: @fmoo I tried it using `multiprocessing.dummy` but didn't get it working. As far as I know multiprocessing creates new processes or threads by pickling and unpickling, which means you can't pass on references. As for the source code, you can find it here: https://github.com/dbrgn/orochi/blob/master/orochi/player.py

Comment: For an example of how simple using Twisted can be, check out the examples on the front page of twistedmatrix.com.  I don't have time for much more than that - I hope that someone gives you a good answer that illustrates how to use it for your use-case though. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems that I figured it out. All my previous attempts at using threads were using the `multiprocessing.dummy` module, which wraps the `threading` module but behaves a little bit different at argument passing - you can't pass references.

Using `threading` directly, it seems to work. I'm doing it by launching a background thread each time I'm loading a new track. When a track has finished playing, I'm sending a `SIGUSR1` signal to the client, which handles it by loading and playing the new song.

*player.py*

```
import os
import signal
import threading
from pipes import quote

class MPlayer(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.process = Process(['mplayer',
            '-slave', '-idle',
            '-really-quiet', '-msglevel', 'global=6:cplayer=4', '-msgmodule',
            '-input', 'nodefault-bindings',
            '-cache', '1024',
        ], bufsize=1)
        self.write_lock = threading.Lock()

    # (...)

    def load(self, path):

        with self.write_lock:
            self.p.write('loadfile {}\n'.format(quote(path)))

        def wait_for_finish(process):
            # HERE: poll process for track ending with process.read()
            os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGUSR1)

        t = threading.Thread(target=wait_for_finish, args=(self.process,))
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
```

*client.py*

```
import cmd
import signal
from player import MPlayer

class PlayCommand(cmd.Cmd, object):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        # (...)

        self.p = MPlayer()
        signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, self._song_end_handler)

    def _song_end_handler(self, signum, frame):
        print('SIGUSR1!!!!!!!!!!111!1')
        # HERE: Fetch new track URL
        self.p.load()
```

Still, if someone thinks he/she has found a better solution using coroutines or events, feel free to answer with your solution.

Comment: One thing to be wary of in your code: Whenever you call `self.p.read()`, you consume / delete *all* of the data that's been written to stdout since the last call.  The current implementation also seems overly complicated, but I haven't dug deep enough to figure out where the synchronization / read issues are coming from

Comment: @fmoo Yeah, I know about that, thanks. At the moment it's not a problem, but I'm trying to clean things up whenever possible. I just commited + pushed a working version, but if you know how to further simplify things, that would be welcome of course.

Comment: To whoever downvoted this answer, why? It is a working solution to a problem with explanation and code examples.

Answer (score 1):

From the look of your code, you could make use of pexpect when communicating with mplayer. Pexpect (or expect for that matter) is perfect for back and forth stdio communication.

Comment: Pexpect looks great, the question is how I can run it asynchronously while still having the possibility of writing to the process' stdin from the outside process/thread (I want to watch the process for the end of a song, but I also want to be able to pause or skip a track). I'd have to share the stdin reference somehow, which would probably cause synchronization problems when using pexpect.

Comment: Pexpect spawns a new process and makes it available to your python script. Do you want it to be reached also by a third party?

Comment: No, but I need to be able to pause the track while at the same time watching the stdout for a "finished playing" like message. The only alternative to a separate thread/process would probably be coroutines. And so far, I haven't figured out how to share a reference to a process' stdout between threads/processes.